# Black screen using AVPlayer (both in simulator and in device)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, video, avplayer

Using this code in an @IBAction of a button the video player opens up but it only shows a black screen. I can't figure out why. Thanks

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Timelapse Stabilizzata", ofType: "mov") {
        let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()


        videoPlayer.player = video

        present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
            video.play()
        })
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **UIwindowLevel**, maybe there is a view appears above the player level

```
         if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Timelapse Stabilizzata", ofType: "mov") {
                let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()

                videoPlayer.view.window?.windowLevel = 0
                videoPlayer.player = video
                present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
                    video.play()
                })
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(